# Aged care, sensors and machine learning

Tags: health-informatics, elderly-seniors-aged-old

What would be valuable to monitor for an aged individual. In order to be able to care for them better.

Im working on a open source project to provide remote monitoring of senior population. 
The idea is to detect anomalies in behaviour and generate alerts if needed.

This is an implementation of the latest buzz word IoT [Internet of things].

Basically Im using AWS IoT platform, and a combination of arduinos and raspberry pis for sensors boxes.

The data collected is analysed searching for patterns and anomalies, That after anonymization can be shared for data science and research purposes.

So basically a bunch of wireless sensors can be used to measure different things like:
. movement
. temperature, humidity, barometric pressure
. Gas, air quality
. object temperature [like a stove/heater]

So one example is that after the system learns what is the normal time a person goes in and out of bed, it can detect an abnormal time staying in bed, and alert if necessary.

What things would be useful to measure in the aged care environment? 
What insights about routines/behaviour are valuable for a carer, doctor/nurse, family member?

Thanks!